# Update property across all objects in array state in React

Tags: reactjs, object, nested, state

In an array of objects I would like to update a certain property across all objects. Let's say my state looks like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([
  {
    number: "4",
    category: "firstCategory"
  },
  {
    number: "6",
    category: "secondCategory"
  }
])
```

How do I reset the `number` property to 0 in all objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const newState = state.map(item => ({...item, number: "0"});
setState(newState);
```

This will build a new (cloned) array where every item is the same as it was but with `number: "0"`, and then updates the state with it